# FM2-A75IA-E53 Wireless Not Working

Tags: wireless, internet

I've just built this Mini-ITX computer to use Ubuntu exclusively and the motherboard "[FM2-A75IA-E53](http://uk.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A75IA-E53.html)" has built in wireless (with a small connector in the back and a supplied antenna). However Ubuntu doesn't seem to be picking it up at all.

At the moment I'm using a USB wireless adapter but preferably I'd like to use the built in adapter, does anyone have any ideas as to drivers I could download to try and resolve this? I've tried installing MadWIFI following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Atheros#KurianAlternative) but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the link you gave above, I downloaded the WLAN driver and it appears your device is an Atheros device driven by the driver ath9k_htc. It requires firmware that is not installed by default. Using the USB, get an internet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot and see if your device is working. If not, edit your question to add the results of these commands:

```
lsusb
dmesg | grep ath9
```

The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with backslash.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I'll try it soon and let you know if it worked. :)